# How can I add id by 1 for input field in each for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

My current html code is:

```
<div id="app">
   <div class="row" v-for="(book, index) in seziure" :key="index">
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label"> Details</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="book.details" id="'transliterateTextarea'+(index+1)">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <a @click="addNewRow">Add Another</a>
</div>
```

But I think id is not changing.

What is the error in that. Actually I am looking for transliteration id's to be changed for each input fields.

I am able to change transliteration ids by the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function transliterateInit(idNo) {
        // Load the Google Transliterate API
        google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages: "transliteration"
        });

        var options = {
            sourceLanguage: google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
            destinationLanguage: [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.MALAYALAM],
            shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
            transliterationEnabled: true
        };

        // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
        // options.
        var control =
            new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

        // Enable transliteration in the textbox with id
        // 'transliterateTextarea'.
        var ids = ["transliterateTextarea" + idNo];
        control.makeTransliteratable(ids);
    }
</script>
```

**My vue js code is:**

```
addForm = new Vue({
    el: "#addForm",
    data: {
        seziure: [{
            details: null,

        }, ],
        mounted: function () {
            transliterateInit(1);
        },
        methods: {
            addNewRow: function () {
                this.seziure.push({
                    date: null,
                    details: null
                });
                transliterateInit(this.seziure.length);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I have able to update transliteration id's.

I AM NOT ABLE TO UPDATE ID's in the input fields. Please help me to update id's in the input field.

Comment: bind the id using `v-bind`. so change `id="'transliterateTextarea'+(index+1)` to `v-bind:id="'transliterateTextarea'+(index+1)"`

Comment: Uncaught Error: Exception in makeTransliteratable: Invalid element id transliterateTextarea2
    at Yy (transliteration.I.js:178)
    at Xy.Q.ij (transliteration.I.js:323)
    at transliterateInit (offencedetails:604)
    at Vue$3.addNewRow (offencedetails:672)
    at boundFn (vue.js:167)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.invoker (vue.js:1732)

Comment: this is the error coming. it is saying transliterateTextarea2  is not present in input fields

Comment: Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the transliterateTextarea data in the Vue instance's data.

Comment: Sir can you please help me .. how to achieve the answrer.. please have a help

Comment: there is a little problem , you put the methods property in data property, you should put the methods property in the Vue instance。

Comment: can you please show sir.. I am not getting.. I tried,, please help